# Sort by date + pull up by boolean

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have items in a sqlite database. Each item has a date, written in the format: YYYY-MM-DD. Of course, several items can have the same date.

Also, the items have the boolean "new". I would like to sort these items by date, with a sql query such as:

```
ORDER BY date DESC
```

That's easy. Now, I would like to pull up the items with the boolean new set to True. What I would like is, if two items have the same date, but one is new and the other is not, the new one must be returned first.

Right now, if two items have the same date, they are returned randomly sorted (or sorted on their primary index key, I don't know).

I don't know if I'm crystal clear.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the new true value a 1 , and anything else a 0 then order by that value descending.

```
select * from table_name 
  order by 
        date desc, 
        case when new='true' then 1 else 0 end desc
```

Tested in this **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/beb3a/6)**